# Is the desingularization of this surfaces of general type?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, singularity-theory, deformation-theory

I have a family of deformation $\mathcal{X}\to B$ of a surface $S$. The surface has a finite number of singular point and it is normal.
There is a divisor $D\subset B$ such that the surface $\mathcal{X}_b$ is smooth and of general type for $b\notin D$. I think that Hironaka's desingularization of $S$ should be of general type too. It is true?

For example, is it true that the deformation of the desingularization is the desingularization of the deformation? This would resolve my problem, as the deformation of a surface of general type results again in a surface of general type, and the resolution of a smooth surface is the same surface.

Thank you!

Comment: The desigularization of $\mathcal{X}$ is not smooth over $B$ in general. For example, if there is nontrivial monodromy over $B^*$, you can never produce a smooth family by modifying the singular fibers.

Comment: Ok, do you have any idea on how to check if the desingularization of $S$ is of general type? Thank you!

Comment: My previous comment will be true if one allows a finite base change on $B$, if we assume isolated singularities are at worst DuVal or Groenstein (for example, see Kollár and Shepherd-Barron, _Threefolds and deformations of surface singularties_, Theorem 2.2, 2.4). In other words, you can still put the desingularization of $S$ in a smooth family of surfaces of general type.